# Problems rotating in the middle of a pan with UIViewPageController-based slide show

Tags: ios

I have an image slide-show viewer that uses a UIPageViewController to present the images.
The image-view viewer ViewController is pretty simple -- a top-level view containing a UIScrollView containing a UIImageView.  On initial image presentation or when the device is rotated the image is aspect-fitted to the view dimensions and centered.  It works fine except for a problem which happens on both iOS 7 and iOS 6.

If I am in the middle of panning to change images and two images are on the screen and I then rotate the device it sometimes (maybe always?) messes up the display of one or more images.  The previously-centered image appears in the wrong place on the screen and this persists when rotated and zoomed.

The only thing I can find *wrong* when this happens is that the center property of the UIImageView is not, in fact, the center of the frame.  If I change the center property of the UIImageView in viewDidAppear to be the center of the possibly-scaled UIImageView then the images seem to display correctly in all cases.

Does this sound like the effect of some familiar mistake that I'm making?

Edit to respond to the question:
I don't do anything in the willRotate or didRotate methods.
In **viewDidLayoutSubviews** I aspect-fit the image into the current UIScrollView bounds (which is the full top-level view which is the full screen) and center it.  This takes care of both the initial presentation and rotations.  I don't see any problems in "normal" rotation situations.  The problem occurs only when I rotate with two of the pageViewController's children views both partly onscreen at once.  I can "fix" the problem in all cases but surely I'm doing something wrong.

Edit 2
I've discovered another anomaly that occurs less frequently when rotating the device while panning with 2 images onscreen.  Best explained by an example:

The page view controller is being used to display one image in a sequence of images from left to right of A B C.  Image B is onscreen.  During a pan to the left you see part of both images A and B.  If the pan to image A is nearly complete, i.e. B is nearly offscreen, and you rotate the device then image B normally ends up onscreen (it never rotates still showing the partial pan), but sometimes image C ends up being displayed -- as though you had panned in the other direction.  Anybody else see this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in your UIViewController to prepare for the rotation?

```
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

And then how do you recover once the rotation has finished?

```
- didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation
```

These calls are provided specifically so you have a chance to get ready for a rotation, and then to put everything back to normal once it completes.